# How do I properly access temp tables created in another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following:

```
use db1;

select * into #db1_tmp from mytable;

use db2;

select * into #db2_tmp from myothertable;

-- join temp table 1 and 2

select * from #db1_tmp a
left join db2_tmp b on where a.uid = b.uid;
```

This works, but SQL Server Management Studio is red-underlining `#db1_tmp` in the last query and therefore in all other statements that depend on this table.

Question: what is the proper way to access a temp table created in another database to prevent this underlining from happening? I tried `db1.#db1_tmp` but this does not work. I'm on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: `select * into #db1_tmp from db1.dbo.mytable;` and `select * into #db2_tmp from db2.dbo.myothertable;` will allow you to create both temp tables from the same database context.  Note that temp tables are created in `tempdb`'

Comment: Temp tables aren't created in user databases.  They are created in `tempdb`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Temp tables actually appear in their own database, TempDB. I think the root of your issue is the `use` statements. Try this instead:

```sql
select * into #db1_tmp from db1.dbo.mytable;
select * into #db2_tmp from db2.dbo.myothertable;

-- join temp table 1 and 2

select * from #db1_tmp a
left join db2_tmp b on where a.uid = b.uid;
```

But if this is the extent of what you're doing (creating the temp tables just to do a join across the databases), you can skip the temp tables altogether:

```sql
select * from db1.dbo.mytable a join db2.dbo.myothertable b on a.uid = b.uid.
```

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables has no use of Database reference for creation so gets created in tempdb.
Only the source can be changed with "use" or "dbname.dbo.mytable".

The red-underlining is due to intellisense. The temp table is just identified as a normal table before execution and redlined due to database change.

Note: The select query at the last has syntax errors.
it should be,

> select * from #db1_tmp a left join #db2_tmp b on a.uid = b.uid;